# Unknown prop `float` on <div> tag

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm creating a component and I want to pass a style attribute via props to an internal div, but I get this error when trying to assign **float:left**

> Unknown prop `float` on  tag. Remove this prop from the element.

My component:

```
<Badge style={{width:'10em',float:'left'}} 
      color={props.user.color}
      initials={props.user.initials}
      name={props.user.name} />
```

the component code:

```
render() {
    const {color,initials, name, style} = this.props;
    return (
      <div {...style}>
        <div className="badge-wrapper">
          <div style={{'backgroundColor': color}} className="badge">
            {
              initials.toUpperCase()
            }
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#">{name}</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I don't see the issue with setting up a **float left** on a simple div, any recommendations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
<div {...style}>
```

to

```
<div style={style}>
```

You are using JSX Spread attributes to apply your css properties to the div as attributes when all you really wanted to do was assign them to the style prop.